# Hyper-V PowerShell - Run a bash command in Linux VM and get output

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, remote-access, hyper-v

Suppose you have

1. Windows Server with Hyper-V and PowerShell 5.1. You can add and use any PowerShell modules such as "Hyper-V".
2. Linux virtual machine. It's generic so you are not allowed to install uncommon applications such as PowerShell Core.

Now you are using (1) Hyper-V where you can run a PowerShell script.

**Question.** How do you run Bash commands on (2) Linux VM and get the output of it using that PowerShell from Hyper-V?

I believe this question is equivalent to **create and run question.ps1 that runs bash /tmp/linux.sh in the Linux VM and get the desired output 100** where /tmp/linux.sh is shown in the image.

[image: enter image Run PowerShell in Hyper-V to run a Bash command and get output]

```
|          | Hyper-V (host)  | Linux VM (guest) |
|----------|-----------------|------------------|
| IPv4     | 10.0.0.1        | 10.0.0.200       |
| hostname | hyperv          | vm               |
| Username | userH           | userL            |
| Password | passwordH       | passwordL        |
| Script   | C:\question.ps1 | /tmp/linux.sh    |
```

Comment: If the SSH server component already is installed in your Linux VM or you're allowed to install it, use SSH from the Windows machine; perhaps this helps: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/497728/HowplustoplusUseplusSSHplustoplusAccessplusaplusLi

Comment: Please read the original question:  Use PowerShell, not SSH by a human user.  And please do not remove the table which is not even JavaScript.  I am pretty sure I need IPv4/hostname, username, password and the script (path) for Hyper-V host and Linux VM guest in your question.ps1 script.

Comment: Sorry for removing the table  - it certainly didn't render a such, and the connection to the question was not obvious in the garbled original representation (raw CSS and HTML snippets).

Comment: I've read the original question. My suggestion was to call SSH _from PowerShell_ in order to execute a Bash script on Linux and capture its output. I don't know what "User PowerShell, not SSH by a human user." means.

Comment: The linked page you provided (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/497728/HowplustoplusUseplusSSHplustoplusAccessplusaplusLi) does not cover how to send a command (maybe via SSH) from PowerShell scripts, just like how we do it using Paramiko for Python. To launch PuTTY on Windows Hyper-V host and log into the Linux VM via SSH" doesn't really help.

Comment: PuTTY comes with CLI `plink.exe`, which "is a command-line connection tool similar to UNIX `ssh`" - https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Recall.* In the Linux VM, you have `/tmp/linux.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

val=100
echo "$val"
exit $?
```

**Answer (Confirmed)**.  Store PuTTY in Windows Hyper-V host.

**Tips.** PuTTY Portable suffices: https://portableapps.com.

Suppose you have stored PuTTY Portable in C:\PortableApps\PuTTYPortable.

Create a PowerShell script file `C:\Users\userH\Desktop\question.ps1`

```
C:\PortableApps\PuTTYPortable\App\putty\PLINK.EXE 10.0.0.200 -l userL -pw passwordL -batch bash /tmp/linux.sh
```

^^ Put this line somewhere in this PowerShell script file.

In PowerShell, run the script file `question.ps1`:

```
PS C:\> & "C:\Users\userH\Desktop\question.ps1"
100
PS C:\>
```

Comment: Gratitude: This answer is based on comments by `mklement0`.